# Hg: How to Restore Changes That Were Backed Out?

Tags: mercurial

I made and committed changes to my branch.

Someone else mistakenly merged and committed those changes to the default branch.

To fix their mistake, they used `hg backout` on default.

Then people committed a bunch of other changes to default.

I didn't realise the backout had happened, and wanted the latest changes. So I merged and committed default into my branch.

Now, the current state of my branch doesn't contain my changes.

What's the right way to get my earlier changes back and preserve the unrelated changes from default that I want to keep?

So far, I've tried merging my earlier changing into my working copy, but it doesn't like merging with an ancestor, and I've tried exporting the changes as a patch and importing them again, but get errors on the import.

It's funny, I'm liking switching to Mercurial from Subversion, but every time I think I might be getting the hang of it, some new bump like this crops up :-P

Comment: wouldn't backing out the original backout work?

Comment: @Idan K: it would, but that's a boring way of putting it. My answer's cooler ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backout the backout. It's just an ordinary commit changing what was changed back, so it should work fine, changing what was changed back back.

Comment: Answers like that are fun to write.

Comment: I think you and Idan K are right. I needed to read http://bit.ly/eXYP7e and http://bit.ly/gZPsHr better to understand what it actually does. I was worried it would result in the changes I wanted to un-backout being on the default branch

Comment: `backout` isn't magic like `rollback` or `strip` or some other things. It just says "in the range you've specified, this, this and this changed. I'll change them back and then commit it". So you can backout the backout in just the same way.

Comment: Yo dawg, i heard u like backouts, so we put a commit in your commit, so you can back out while you back out.

Comment: One of the great things about mercurial is that because you have a local copy of all the changesets, you can update and commit while disconnected from the other repositories - even if you're in a desert in the middle of Australia or something. And that means you can back out in the outback.

Comment: @Tom: grooaannn... but still +1 :P  Melbourne, where I live, isn't very outbacky, I'm afraid. Perhaps that's why I've never actually used `backout`. (Or perhaps it's just that I've never had a need to yet.)

Comment: As a side note, you want to hg up to your original branch, then backout the changeset for the actual backout, then commit. Don't backout the merge from default that contained the backout, as you may lose other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get the rev number then clone it :

`hg log --style compact`

`hg clone -r REV your-current-repo new-repo`